# Why do I get undefined when adding a const and a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In a config.js file I have the following.

```
export const STATUS = 'local';
export const BASE_URL = {
    'local': 'http://localhost:8000/'
}
export const API_URL = BASE_URL[STATUS] + 'api/';
```

Which I import into another file

Which works fine

```
import 'theconfig' from './config'

console.log(theconfig.API_URL)
```

I get the correct response

> http://localhost:8000/api/

But if I do this

```
console.log(theconfig.API_URL + 'user');
```

I get this

> http://localhost:8000/api/undefineduser

Why is the undefined word showing between my two strings? I assume because I'm concatenating a constant and string, but it works in the config file when I append 'api/' to the end of the string from BASEURL when creating the new const API_URL? How do I achieve the desired result without having this issue?

EDIT:

Seems that there was also a export default that didn't include the data which caused this to happen. After I added the constats to the export under a slightly different variable name, everything functions as expected.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem, because from the little code you've shown the output `http://localhost:8000/api/undefineduser` isn't possible when `console.log(theconfig.API_URL)` logs `http://localhost:8000/api/`

Comment: Also, can you please share the result of console.log(\`${theconfig.API_URL} /user\`);

Comment: import directly {API_URL} i think this will work

Comment: if i'm not mistaken that is babel syntax, so the issue is going to be from it, i tested using classic `module.exports and require()` and it works as expected.